# Delete cookies after click on revoke button

Tags: javascript

I want to make a revoke button what delete google analytics cookies `_ga` and `_gid`

My JS code:

```
 $('.wpca-btn-reset-consent').click(function(e) {
            var domainValue = "www.mysite.eu";
            document.cookie = '_ga=; path=/; domain='+ domainValue + '; expires=' + new Date(0).toUTCString();
            document.cookie = '_gid=; path=/; domain='+ domainValue + '; expires=' + new Date(0).toUTCString();
            alert("Done");
    });
```

After I press button I get Done alert but cookies are not deleted.

Comment: Just set the expires parameter to a past date

Answer (score 0):

create a function and then try this way

function deleteCookie(yourName) {
document.cookie = yourName + '=; yourPath=/; yourDomain=.example.com; Expires=Thu, 30 Jan 2023 00:00:01 GMT;';
}

Comment: Your solution just make a new cookie and even if I change expire date to 1970 cookies still are not removed.